# Angular Material mdMenu

Tags: angular, angular-material2

I am struggling makign work the classList @input property in the mdMenu directive. I need to change the layout of it using this property. I have the work around but this requires to add style for the entire app but I do not want that. I really believe this classList property is more dynamic and can be set differently for each component.

Please provide me an example of have can a make this work.

In advance, thank you so much.

[image]

This is my how my code looks like.

[image]

Result in the browser:
[image]

Comment: How do you use it?

Comment: I just updated my question and put my code at the bottom. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should pass string like:

```
class="class1 class2"
```

or

```
[class]="'class1 class2'"
```

**[Plunker Example](https://plnkr.co/edit/MgTL1GA1jdy4lpuf7rCu?p=preview)**

Comment: I tried that and it did not work. Well if the class name is in the main css file it will work but why it is not working on it own css file component?

Comment: See my plunker. I use `::ng-deep` to apply css to nested element. See also https://angular.io/guide/component-styles#deprecated-deep--and-ng-deep

Comment: ::ng-deep did the trick. Thanks so much, I appreciate your help.